# ASP.NET Core : specify controller name for logging in using identity

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

How to specify controller name for login, it always redirect me to Account/Login, I'm using different controller and I moved the login action to it but I can't use that action, Is there a default controller name setting in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change in :

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
     options.LoginPath = new PathString("/identity/Account/Login");
     options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/identity/Account/AccessDenied");
}
```